# CTRL+C, CTRL+V, text selection via SHIFT + arrow in Windows cmd

Tags: windows, cmd

I using cmd actively for creating/testing shell command and I'm interested how to allow standard text operation hotkeys like <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd>, selecting via <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>arrow</kbd>.

Is it possible and how to do that?

Comment: Hm, interesting. Why some people vote to close question?

Comment: The question appears to be off-topic. Hence the close votes. You'll need to use a different console to meet your goals. Not going to happen in cmd.

Comment: I also asking is it possibe. If it's not possible so the answer is 'No, cmd do not allow to do that'. SO I think that the question is very specific and allow to get exact answer. And it not offtopic for cmd.

Comment: It's deemed off topic on SO because it's not about code. It's a perfectly decent superuser Q, but it's not an SO Q.

Comment: faq says that it's allowed to asked questions about 'software tools commonly used by programmers'. Cmd is commonly used tool, so it's the correct place for that question.

Comment: I think it means tools that are specific to programming. I mean, you use Windows all the time. Asking questions about how to do X, Y and Z in Explorer would be SU not SO. That's just my interpretation anyway. What's more I think you'll get better answers over on SU. Close votes to migrate are not necessarily a negative thing.

Answer (score 1):

Why you don't try with "[PowerCMD](http://www.powercmd.com/)" you have plenty of shortcuts with that program.

PowerCmd is a better command prompt replacement tool that enhances your command prompt with an easy-to-use Windows GUI interface and allows you to run multiple command consoles simultaneously in a tab-based windows.

It has many features i'm positive you are going to find it useful.

Greetings.

Comment: is it possible to open 3rd party tools which normally using cmd in it?

Comment: Sorry, but i don't know. If you can try and give us feedback about that it would be really nice!

Answer (score 1):

With [Console](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/) you can configure the hotkeys for `copy` and `paste`. I'm not aware of a way to enable selecting via <kbd>Shift</kbd> + cursor keys, though.

Answer (score 1):

Copy and paste in a command window is made slightly easier if you enable QuickEdit mode (in Properties/Options).  This means that you can make the selection by dragging with the mouse without having to do Edit -> Mark first. Once you've done then there's one keystroke worth memorising:

```
alt-space E P
```

This will open up the window menu and choose Edit -> Paste. I use this so much that it's now quite natural to me.  The Console app that Ansgar recommends does make this easier, but if you need to use the regular cmd.exe then this trick works well.